# Rails: Set variable using link_to "new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to accomplish the following without being certain it is even possible, so it would be really great if someone could help me!

I have a Quiz object, and after it hast been created I want wo be able to do create a new level with:

<= link_to 'New Level', new_level_path(@quiz), :quiz_id => @quiz.id > (%% is missing because not shown properly)

With :quiz_id => @quiz.id I thougt to set the level variable "quiz_id" to the id of the quiz, from the previous page. (Level belongs to Quiz)

What I did make happen is

http.../levels/new.36

36 being the ID of my quiz. How do I get this number to be set as the quiz_id variable of the level I want to create?

I tried something like:

<= f.number_field :quiz_id, :value => @Quiz.id> (%% is missing because not shown properly)
<= f.number_field :quiz_id, :value => "current_quiz_id">  (%% is missing because not shown properly)

but that doesn't seem to work. Can this be done? Can I "preset" variables trough "link_to" new_level_path or is there any other way to create an object out of the view of the object it belongs to and preset some variables?

I would really appritiate any help!

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I solved my own problem through some trial and error. I changed the link_to to:

<= link_to( 'New Level', new_level_path(@quiz, :quiz_id => @quiz.id)) > (%% is missing for formating reasons)

and in the levels_controller I added the following to the new method:
 @quiz_id= params[:quiz_id]

Through that I could use the @quiz_id variable in the level.new view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem through some trial and error. I changed the link_to to:

<= link_to( 'New Level', new_level_path(@quiz, :quiz_id => @quiz.id)) > (%% is missing for formating reasons)

and in the levels_controller I added the following to the new method: @quiz_id= params[:quiz_id]

Through that I could use the @quiz_id variable in the level.new view.